# Total number of members of a group

Tags: facebook-fql, facebook-group

I have this code. I am trying to show the total number of people who have joined a group.

```
perPage = 500
    for count in range(100):
        res = fql('SELECT uid FROM group_member WHERE gid = 457030854323270 limit 500 offset 500' % (fbUserId, perPage, perPage * count))
        if len(res) == 0:
            break
        friends += len(res)
```

Does it need a loop? I wouldn't know how to write it, though...

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  this is facebook I really don't know how this works, you can try this.  If its wrong let me know in comments I will remove it.

can you not just

```
SELECT Count(uid) from group_member WHERE gid = 457030854323270 limit 500 offset 500' % (fbUserId, perPage, perPage * count))
```

that would return the total number of results?

Comment: Can you please post the whole code? With <?php tags. Thank you.

Comment: Afraid I can't I don't know php that well.  I just recognized the select statment as sql statement, and I was basing my answer off that.   I made an edit to my code, I had made a mistake.  but most of the Select statement was based on your original statement.  but instead of selecting a record I just selected a total count. so you will only get one result  which will be the total number of records

Comment: Ok here is the query, but what needs the connection to be established with?

    $pic = mysql_query("SELECT pic_small from group WHERE gid = 457030854323270");
    $count = mysql_query("SELECT Count(uid) from group_member WHERE gid = 457030854323270 limit 500 offset 500");

    while($output = mysql_fetch_array($pic, $count))
    {
    echo $output['pic'] . "<br />";
    echo $output['count'];
    }
  
    mysql_free_result($pic, $count);

Comment: K'leg is the bit you wrote "(fbUserId, perPage, perPage * count)" needed?

Comment: I have no idea, that was on your original post.  As I said I just took what you wrote, but changed it so that it returns the total number of rows, instead of returning the rows themself.